# Python date module for mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, pytest, pymongo

Year=2023 month=4 day=28 Userdate = datetime.datetime(year,month, day) For rec in collec.find({“createdat”{“$lte”:datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(userdate)}}): print(rec)

Type error fromisoformat: argument must be str”

Comment: Have a look at [datetimes and timezones](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/datetimes.html#datetimes-and-timezones).  To query MongoDB you will probably need to use `datetime` instead of `date`

Comment: Can you run a `db.colleciton.findOne()` in the mongo shell and report back a sample document.

Comment: I'm asking to see what format your dates are in. It will either be a string or a date (ISODate).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB stores dates as [BSON](https://bsonspec.org/spec.html) type 9, which stores the number of milliseconds since 1970-01-01 00:00 UTC.

This means that a year-month-day is not specific enough to be a MongoDB timestamp.

Instead of `{$gte: datetime.date(2023,5,2)}`, try `{$gte: datetime.datetime(2023,5,2,0,0,0)}`

In the second case you are querying for a string.  Since mongodb query operators are type-sensitive, that will never match a date, try:

```
collection.find({"create":{"$gte": ISODate("2023-04-27T19:47:00Z")}})
```